# CentOS 5.4 black screen during installation

Tags: centos, installation

I'm trying to install **CentOS 5.4** on my machine and very early in the anaconda installer when my graphics card is detected I think the X server should go up but the screen goes black and it stays that way.

What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

During boot before the gui installation you can chose a text based install by typing `linux text` at the `boot:` prompt. [Here is an overview](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/s1-guimode-textinterface-x86.html) of the text based menus.

Comment: +1 text install.  I never use the graphical installer.

Comment: I'm gonna give it a try... I'm no expert so command lines frighten me! Thanks.

Comment: Text based install went well... now when I logon and try to run startx same behaviour happens: black screen.